# Calculate values shifting by column or looping over column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops

I have the following dataframe, first to calculate the following math operation year+n/year.value==2009 for every cohort and then perform the mean for each cohort

```
df
             id                                                        
year       2009     2010     2011     2012     2013     2014     2015   
cohort                                                                  
2009.0  72092.0  60513.0  48797.0  40968.0  34919.0  30452.0  26961.0   
2010.0      NaN  73735.0  61899.0  50263.0  42184.0  36150.0  31516.0   
2011.0      NaN      NaN  76809.0  64093.0  51372.0  43277.0  36994.0   
2012.0      NaN      NaN      NaN  69776.0  57621.0  46453.0  39098.0   
2013.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  71613.0  58996.0  47657.0   
2014.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  65430.0  52540.0   
2015.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  67121.0   
2016.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   
2017.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
```

I will show the math operation that i want to perform because my english is not good and math is a universal language :)

For whenever 1 year pass since 2009: (n=1)

first value needed = ((60513.0/72092.0) + (61899.0/73735.0) + (64093.0+76809.0) + (57621.0/69776.0) + (58996.0+71613.0) + (52540.0/65430.0))/6

For whenever 2 year pass since 2009: (n=2)

second value needed = ((48797.0/72092.0) + (50263.0/73735.0) + (51372.0/76809.0) + (46453.0/69776.0) + (47657.0/71613.0))/5

For whenever 3 year pass since 2009: (n=3) (Last one, i think with this one the looping of what i want to do will be understand)

third value needed = ((40968.0/72092.0) + (42184.0/73735.0) + (43277.0/76809.0)
+ (39098.0/69776.0))/4

And so on until the last value would be

last value = 26961.0/72092.0

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english

I am trying somethin like this, maybe it can help

First value:

```
 ((df1.iloc[0,1]/df1.iloc[0,0]) + (df1.iloc[1,2]/df1.iloc[1,1]) + 
 (df1.iloc[2,3]/df1.iloc[2,2]) + (df1.iloc[3,4]/df1.iloc[3,3]) + 
 (df1.iloc[4,5]/df1.iloc[4,4]) + (df1.iloc[5,6]/df1.iloc[5,5]))/6
```

Second value:

```
 ((df1.iloc[0,2]/df1.iloc[0,0]) + (df1.iloc[1,3]/df1.iloc[1,1]) + 
 (df1.iloc[2,4]/df1.iloc[2,2]) + (df1.iloc[3,5]/df1.iloc[3,3]) + 
 (df1.iloc[4,6]/df1.iloc[4,4]))/5
```

Third value:

```
 ((df1.iloc[0,3]/df1.iloc[0,0]) + (df1.iloc[1,4]/df1.iloc[1,1]) + 
 (df1.iloc[2,5]/df1.iloc[2,2]) + (df1.iloc[3,6]/df1.iloc[3,3]))/4
```

Something like this but with a loop

Comment: Code is a universal language. What have you tried?

Comment: really i am new at python, i looked some questions, but my codes that i tried are not usefull at all

Comment: There i tried something, but for sure it must be a more elegant way

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

---- UPDATED ----

```
import numpy as np

def sum_with_shift(df, n):
    row_values = []
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        if (i + n - 1) < df.columns.max():  
            row_values += [row[i] / row[i + n]]

    if row_values:
        return np.mean(row_values)
    else:
        return 0
```

passing your `df` and `n=1`:

```
sum_with_shift(df, 1)

72092.0 / 60513.0
73735.0 / 61899.0
76809.0 / 64093.0
69776.0 / 57621.0
71613.0 / 58996.0
65430.0 / 52540.0

130852.83333333333
```

passing your `df` and `n=2`:

```
sum_with_shift(df, 2)

72092.0 / 48797.0
73735.0 / 50263.0
76809.0 / 51372.0
69776.0 / 46453.0
71613.0 / 47657.0

121713.39999999999
```

---- UPDATED ----

For reproducibility, try running the below code to generate your `df`.

```
df_as_json = '{"2009":{"2009":72092.0,"2010":null,"2011":null,"2012":null,"2013":null,"2014":null,"2015":null,"2016":null,"2017":null},"2010":{"2009":60513.0,"2010":73735.0,"2011":null,"2012":null,"2013":null,"2014":null,"2015":null,"2016":null,"2017":null},"2011":{"2009":48797.0,"2010":61899.0,"2011":76809.0,"2012":null,"2013":null,"2014":null,"2015":null,"2016":null,"2017":null},"2012":{"2009":40968.0,"2010":50263.0,"2011":64093.0,"2012":69776.0,"2013":null,"2014":null,"2015":null,"2016":null,"2017":null},"2013":{"2009":34919.0,"2010":42184.0,"2011":51372.0,"2012":57621.0,"2013":71613.0,"2014":null,"2015":null,"2016":null,"2017":null},"2014":{"2009":30452.0,"2010":36150.0,"2011":43277.0,"2012":46453.0,"2013":58996.0,"2014":65430.0,"2015":null,"2016":null,"2017":null},"2015":{"2009":26961.0,"2010":31516.0,"2011":36994.0,"2012":39098.0,"2013":47657.0,"2014":52540.0,"2015":67121.0,"2016":null,"2017":null}}'

df = pd.read_json(df_as_json)
```

Comment: row_values += [row[i] + row[i + n]] would be really like this or not? row_values += [row[i] / row[i + n]]

Comment: Sorry but i try and throw me an error, TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'tuple'

Comment: you're right that it should be "/" instead of "+". as for the error -- i suspect that its because the dataframes are formatted a bit differently. try replacing ````df.columns.max()```` with 2015

Comment: thank you, but still throwing, TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'tuple'

Comment: I've added a way for you to reproduce the dataframe that I'm using. Try and see if you can apply the function to that. If it works, try to format your dataframe in the same way, or edit the function to match your version.

Comment: There i edit my answer with a monkey answer, maybe that helps to reproduce a more elegant way

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you are trying to iterate from the first year (column) to the last year (column) in the table. Then, in your math you are doing basically the same thing except from the year your currently iterating on to the last year. It looks like you need a loop

```
numcols = 6 # Set this to the correct value
for year in range(0, numcols-1):
    count = numcols - year
    sum = 0
    for x in range(year, numcols-1):
        sum += df1.iloc[x-year,1+x]/df1.iloc[x-year,x-year]
    print("Answer for this year is: {}".format(sum/count))
```